# select distinct from table mysql

Tags: mysql

I cant filter in a good way my table, this is my table:

```
+----------+-----------+-------+------+
| PersonID | FirstName | Level | Time |
+----------+-----------+-------+------+
|    1     |   Beru    |   51  |  22  |
|    2     |   Pepe    |   42  |  13  |
|    3     |   Tom     |   30  |  15  |
|    4     |   Beru    |   51  |  32  |
|    5     |   Tom     |   28  |  15  |
|    ....  |    ...    |  .... |  ... |
+----------+-----------+-------+------+
    ........................... more players
```

I want to order it by Bigger Level and Time, but not repeating FirstName and only 5 first, its posible? thanks.

So my Output Should be some stuff like this:

```
- FirstName - Level - Time
- Beru      - 51    - 32
- Pepe      - 42    - 13
- Tom       - 30    - 15
-  .... more players...
```

I hope someone can help me. I know what to use, but i dont know how to use it.

```
SELECT o.FirstName, o.Level, o.Time
FROM myTable o
GROUP BY FirstName
ORDER BY o.Level*100+o.Time  DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

thanks everyone, obviusly that mysql script doesnt work, i hope you know how to do it, :)

Comment: Why would there be 'more players' in the output?

Comment: the limit is 10, and there are only 3, so there should be 7 more players :)

Comment: 'and only 5 first' ??

Comment: It is just an example men....

Comment: Cool. Examples are generally more helpful if they illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in order to get the greatest-per-player record:

```
SELECT PersonID, FirstName, Level, Time
FROM (
  SELECT PersonID, FirstName, Level, Time,
         @rn := IF(@name = FirstName, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@name := FirstName, 1, 1)) AS rn                 
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @name := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY FirstName, Level DESC, Time DESC) AS t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY FirstName LIMIT 0, 5
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acd84/3)

Comment: theres is a little problem, sometimes people use as firstName, numbers, for example :FirstName = 123Beto456, so if you use this, it gives u an error, look : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a08d/1

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña So you want to filter these records out? This seems to be a different problem than the one described in the OP.

Comment: No, i mean, in your script of sql if you put a number as firstname, it gives you an error, cause is not in the right order, but now I updated my mysql and it works in this example, but in my real project is not working yet, idk why :/

Comment: Its not a message error, but if you see the answer, is not order :(

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a fiddle using GROUP_CONCAT:-

```
SELECT FirstName, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Level ORDER BY Level DESC, Time DESC), ',', 1) AS Level,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Time ORDER BY Level DESC, Time DESC), ',', 1) AS Time
FROM myTable
GROUP BY FirstName
```

To order that in the right order:-

```
SELECT FirstName, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Level ORDER BY Level DESC, Time DESC), ',', 1) AS Level,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`Time` ORDER BY Level DESC, Time DESC), ',', 1) AS `Time`
FROM myTable
GROUP BY FirstName
ORDER BY Level*100+`Time`  DESC
LIMIT 10
```

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03457/1

Note that this ordering won't be that efficient (no way to use indexes).

Comment: this have the same problem, of the other one, if you add for example (6, '1bet', 10, 15) to the table, if you excecute it, this is not order in the right way. :(

Comment: Adding the ordering to it